# Can someone travel to the Isle of Man with BRP and passport and no separate visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I am a South African citizen with a valid UK Biometric Residence Permit (BRP). I know I can use the BRP in combination with my passport to leave and enter the UK when travelling.

I need to travel for one week to the Isle of Man. Can I travel to the common travel area (CTA) countries with only my BRP and passport, or do I need to have a separate visa for this? I have researched this online and can't find information specific for expats with BRPs.

The closest I can find is from [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area-cta/common-travel-area-cta), which indicates that I do not need a separate entrance permit if I already have UK entry clearance, which seems enough, but I am not certain.

Does someone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

Not direct experience with Isle of Man, but... I'm a Guernsey citizen living in the US. I have a UK passport at present, because Guernsey requires return TO Guernsey to renew a Guernsey passport, where Her Majesty's Passport Service was able to renew me whilst I was here in the US in the expatriate panic just prior to the election of 45.

I recently traveled home to Guernsey, along with my American then-fiancee now-wife and two kids, and like the Isle of Man, Guernsey is a Crown Dependency, and not part of the UK. I was able to enter UK with my UK passport, as was my fiancee with her American, and we were not asked to present ID on arriving from UK to Guernsey.

She was required to address Guernsey's immigration department as the purpose of the trip was our wedding on the island of Guernsey: typically Crown Dependencies have parallel immigration laws to UK, but not identical.

Once we had entered the British CTA via entry at the UK, we were *not* required to show passports at landing on Guernsey, and as I understand it, Isle of Man has a similar arrangement with UK - full reciprocity.

I think you should be *fine* with your BRP & passport.

I am not an immigration expert, attorney or solicitor.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the answer to my own question through the experience of travelling (flying) from London (Gatwick) to the Isle of Man with my wife and 3 year old child.

There is no passport control in travelling from UK to Isle of Man, you only need to show photo proof of identity for all travellers when going through the boarding gates. A BRP is sufficient for proof of identity, you don't need to take your passport. You also don't need a birth certificate to travel with your child.

Answer (score 0):

Holders of a valid visa for the UK or the Channel Islands can travel freely around the Common Travel Area without the need for applying for a specific visa for the Isle of Man. ([Source](https://www.gov.im/categories/travel-traffic-and-motoring/immigration/visit/))